# Uploading remote server files after git checkout

Tags: phpstorm, remote-server, git-checkout

I am using phpstorm 7 on my windows host for a git project. The files are synced with a VM via phpstorm's **remote server** feature, so each time a save is made, the changed file is also upoloaded to my VM.

I am having difficulties when I am **pulling newer versions from Git** because the only way to send the changed files to my VM is to upload a **full copy** of the project via phpstorm. Or of course I can send them individually but it also takes too **much effort**.

So my question is if there is a feature or plugin for phpstorm which **automatically** uploads only the **changed files** after a git checkout.

Thank you!

Comment: Any VCS changes are considered as **"external change"** -- try enabling similarly named option in Deployment options. Other than that I may only suggest you to: 1) use "Deployment | Sync with deployed.." -- it will sync whole project/selected folders or files; 2) issue similar git checkout command on remote host (IDE supports SSH connections so that you can use remote console).

Answer (score -1):

You can :

- sync src code with option deployement to delete the file that no existing in target location
- create a external tools for sync
- create macro that launch a git pull and after launch a sync
- create external tools for sync AND others for pulling git branch

When you create a macro or external tools don't forget that you can launch those with a shortcut.